# Dos.h + Pc.h in C and Windows Vista

Tags: c, visual-studio, header-files, mesa, pelles-c

I am currently looking to work with Mesa3D to create a software rendered graphic application with OpenGL.

I am looking a a few tutorials right now on how to use it, and many are written with DOS or older versions of Windows in mind. As I run Vista I don't seem to have the right files I need.

The Mesa3D tutorial I am using uses `outportb()` and a few other commands which I can't seem to get working.  After looking around I have found you require the 2 include files:

- dos.h
- pc.h

These do not seem to be found within the Window's SDK that comes with Visual Studio 2010 (Express) or even the older version of 2005 (Professional) which I currently have.

They seem to be found with the **DJGPP** compiler that only works under DOS and is not supported in Vista, even with compatability mode. Running DosBox still does not get this to work.

I am wondering - is there perhaps a new functions replacing `outportb` or can I use these DJGPP files with my C/C++ complier with VS or PellesC (which I find better for C-only programs)?

In addition the **conio.h** include file I have with both VS and PellesC doesn't have the `textmode()` function, but the DJGPP version does.

If anyone could help either getting DJGPP working on Vista or allowing me to use the dos,pc and conio.h files from DJGPP with either VS or PellesC that'd be a great help!

Answer (score 1):

Port-manipulating functions will simply not work in Win32 programs. Either use Win32 APIs to do I/O (rendering included) or stick to DOS and run your program in DOS or whatever DOS emulator you can find that works. Vista and later Windows won't run most DOS programs directly as the support for DOS is either severely reduced or removed altogether (e.g. in 64-bit Windows).

Answer (score 1):

The low-level hardware access that functions like `outportb` give you is not available to programs in modern Windows environments.  Such capabilities are reserved for specially-trusted code (OS internals and drivers).  You need to go through higher-level APIs or drivers in order to access the same functionality.

The Mesa3D website has [a readme for Windows developers](http://www.mesa3d.org/README.WIN32) that has information about what you need to install and configure.  It also references some official demo code that you can use as the basis for your project.  The [Mesa3D website](http://www.mesa3d.org/) also has [a repository full of demo programs](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/demos) that will probably serve as better examples than the out-of-date tutorials that you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use 16bit compilers on vista and higher.. instead use DOSBOX to run your programs.

Comment: Are you saying that DJGPP is a 16-bit complier and so it's headers will not work with the 32-bit compliers of VS and PellesC?

Comment: no, I am saying even if the headers work, it will throw out an error. Instead just use DJGPP with DOSBOX @Ewan

Comment: Ok, I shall try that. I am new to all this Header stuff as I far prefer C#. Thank you however.

Comment: I prefer C# too, its my favorite language besides C and Python